# String concatenation in ActiveRecord in Yii Framework?

Tags: php, frameworks, yii, concatenation

Is it possible to CONCAT values of two table columns using the Yii's ActiveRecord methods and patterns?

If is, how?

I'm currently using this:

```
return $this->findByAttributes(array('alias' => $alias));
```

But in this I need to return the concated string/values.

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for something like that:

```
select username||'@'||domain from user_mail_table;
```

to receive concatenated values - so i don't think, that it's possible.
That's not the idea of ActiveRecord.

If you like to concat values like the example above, you should take DAO
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao
...or if you need ActiveRecord, you should concat the values inside your application

```
$mailaddress=$model->username.'@'.$model->domain;
```

Comment: thanks! you clearified me some thing I've didn't quite understood! thanks, again!

Answer (score 2):

add a method to your model, like this:

```
public function getEmail()
{
  return $this->username.'@'.$this->domain;
}
```

then in views, you can just use the "email" attribute (not getEmail) and you're good to go.

Comment: I was thinking if there is a parameter or something for concatenation, but nevermind. :) This will help aswell ;)

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do it by using the sql **concat** function in your activerecord definition
    ...find()
    ->select(['alias'=>'CONCAT(....)'])
    ->all();

that would produce a column called alias with the values from the columns used in the concat
hope that still helps